# How to show all implementations of interface DTO in swagger?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have rest endpoint for saving some example model and I use SpringFox 2.9.2 to generate JSON documentation of rest endpoint. There is a few implementation of DTO from RequestBody. How can I tell swagger to show all of implementations of generic DTO instead only baseDTO model?

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(CREATED)
public BaseView create(@RequestBody @Validated BaseDTO baseDTO) {
    return service.create(baseDTO);
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = NAME,
    include = PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FirstImplDTO.class, name = "firstDTO"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SecondImplDTO.class, name = "secondDTO")
 })
 public interface BaseDTO {
    Integer getId();
 }
```